What condition of the Hawking singularity theorem fails for de Sitter and Minkowski spacetimes?
I am trying to figure out what condition of the Hawking singularity theorem fails for de Sitter and Minkowski spacetimes. Some has to fails otherwise we would had geodesic incompleteness which its false for these spaces

REFERENCE: Foundations of General Relativity From Einstein to Black Holes by Klaas Landsman
https://radbouduniversitypress.nl/site/books/m/10.54195/EFVF4478/
I think that the problem is condition 3, but why?
For Minkowswki space time would it be a correct argument to say that the 0 curvature implies that $H_0=0$? Would it be correct to state that all Cauchy hypersurfaces must be flat? Why?
For de Sitter space I have no idea how to argue.

Not all, but some are flat.

@MoisheKohan so, how can I argue that Minkowski spacetime fails the condition then?

The easiest proof is to check that the first two conditions hold (clear) and that $R^{n,1}$ is geodesically complete (also clear).
